# Recursive of a Algorithm that identifies if a matrix has or not multiple

Tags: python, recursion

I have to create a function that have to return true if a row in that matrix have no multiple ocurrences and false otherwise. This have to be done by loops, then create the same function with recursion. I was able to do the function using loops below but I just could think how it could be done by recursion.

```
def IsnonrepeatedRow(A):
  count = 0
  for i in range(len(A)):
    for x in range (i+1, len(A)):
      for j in range(len(A[0])):
        if A[i][j] // A[x][j] == 0:
         count += 1
      if count == len(A[0]):
        return True
      count = 0
return False
```

Comment: What do you mean by "have no multiple occurences"? Please show several examples to illustrate. Also, the indentation in yoru code is incorrect. Please [edit] your question to fix this. You need to add 4 extra space before **every*** line, not just the first one. Or use triple backticks before and after the code block.

Answer (score 0):

Basically all you need depends on the "count" value. Therefore you should pass it recursively for each column, add 1 if equals to zero, and at the end of the column check your current condition.

Overall, should not be so different from your current algorithm. The difference is only by passing "count" through recursion.